# How a full node knows which chain to follow?

Tags: consensus, hardforks, blockchain-fork, consensus-by-block

After Istanbul fork, my full node followed the longest chain which has:

1. Longest Chain
2. Highest TotalDifficulty

It seems that the shorter chain of the core-dev closing the gap - total difficulty increasing faster than on the longer chain.

Now the totalDifficulty of the shorter, core-dev chain is larger and still my node didn't switch to it.

What are the parameter to decide which chain to follow?

Is it supposed to happen automatically, what actions do I need to take right now?